# Were all of the "good" terminators played by Arnold Schwarzenegger completely separate machines?

Tags: terminator-series, the-terminator, terminator-dark-fate

Speaking specifically about the live action terminator movies in which Arnold Schwarzenegger played a Terminator fighting on the side of humanity, were each of these machines completely separate Terminators with unique experiences and memories, or were any of them the same machine as in another movie, or from an alternate time line, or from another dimension?

For example, is Pops from Terminator Genisys a past\future version
of Carl from Dark Fate, or is Carl a version of the Terminator from Rise of the Machines from a different timeline?

Answer (score 15):

**#1 - The Terminator (T-800)** : it was destroyed at the end of the movie.

**#2 - Terminator 2: Judgment Day (T-800)** : it's another unit, re-programmed to protect John Connor.

**#3 - Terminator 3: Rise Of The Machines (T-850)** : The T-850 doesn't have much in the way of differences from the previous model, although they're programmed to act in a more human manner.

**#4 - Terminator: Genisys (T-800  "Guardian")** : This machine actually gets an emotional arc too, being sent back in time to protect young Sarah Connor and eventually having to raise her like a father, making him the most human T-800.

**#5 - Terminator: Dark Fate (Carl)** : a [T-800](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Carl) from Sarah's past.

While they have some backups and common databases, these seem to be different units. Maybe Carl isn't, but it's not clear to me.

Read more about [All Of The Terminator Models From The Movies](https://screenrant.com/terminator-models-ranked-power/) and [Every Terminator Arnold Schwarzenegger Has Played](https://screenrant.com/arnold-schwarzenegger-terminator-every-version/)

Comment: Looks like you're misusing the word "model". The model is all the same (T-800) except T3 (T-850). The **units** are different.

Comment: I probably miss a word/meaning once in a while, I'm not a native speaker, I'll check this out.